# php phalanger install: what if php is already installed by Microsoft first?

Tags: php

I want to try PHP phalanger
http://php-compiler.net/doku.php?id=core:phalanger_for_.net_developers#running_php_applications_on_phalanger

Did Microsoft installed PHP phalanger or classical PHP ?

If I want to switch to test PHP Phalang do I need to uninstall php or just modify some config ?

Answer (score 1):

Both PHP and Phalanger are open-source projects independent of Microsoft.

You can have them both installed... Assuming you are using IIS you just have to modify web.config file in a directory of your PHP application so IIS knows which HTTP handler should use for *.php files.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
          <!--<remove name="Phalanger" />--> 
        <remove name="PHP_via_FastCGI"/>
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In this case you will be using Phalanger for handeling PHP files.